# Xcode debugger breaking down in specific class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iPad app that I am working on in Xcode. I came across a bug that I narrowed down to happening in one specific class. However, when I try to go through the methods of that class in the debugger, it starts to go haywire. I try to hit the "Step Over" button, but it doesn't respond. Eventually the debugger buttons (step over, step in, step out) just gray out and the continue button turns to pause like it's continuing. When I press the pause button, though, nothing happens, and as far as I can tell, it's not running the program.

What could be causing the debugger to act like this?

EDIT: I know I'm not giving much detail about the class itself, but the debugger has been able to go through this class before, when an infinite loop was running and I was trying to find where it was happening.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior in the simulator and on the device?

Comment: It's all on the simulator. I've been having issues with trying to run this on a device...

Comment: ok, then on what exact command does it stop? Is there some multi threading going on? Might it be a deadlock? Do you run it in debug or release configuration?

Comment: It stops on any command within the class itself, there isn't any multi threading happening, and I'm running it in the debug configuration. What do you mean by deadlock? Also, sorry for not replying in a while